# Create Cursor that Iterates through Views?

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
-- Product(maker, model, type)
-- PC(model, speed, ram, hd, price)
-- Laptop(model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
-- Printer(model, color, type, price)
```

These are the tables. Product.model is the primary key. PC.model, Laptop.model, and Printer.model are foreign keys that reference Product.model.

For each view (code below), I would like to create a cursor that iterates through the list of models and concatenates the entries so that it looks like this -> `"maker '-' type model 'for' price"`

```
create view PCView
as select Product.maker, Product.type, PC.model, PC.speed, PC.ram, PC.hd, PC.price
from PC, Product
where PC.model = Product.model;

create view LaptopView
as select Product.maker, Product.type, Laptop.model, Laptop.speed, Laptop.ram, Laptop.hd, Laptop.screen, Laptop.price
from Laptop, Product
where Laptop.model = Product.model;

create view PrinterView
as select Product.maker, Product.type, Printer.model, Printer.color, Printer.type as printerType, Printer.price
from Printer, Product
where Printer.model = Product.model;
```

I know there are easier ways of doing it but I have attempted using a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE createProductList ( INOUT productList varchar(4000) )
BEGIN
     DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE PCViewList varchar(100) DEFAULT "";
     -- declare cursor for PCView
     DEClARE cursorViewPC CURSOR FOR SELECT model FROM PCView;
     -- declare NOT FOUND handler
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
     OPEN cursorViewPC;
    getProduct: LOOP
          FETCH cursorViewPC INTO PCViewList;
         IF finished = 1 THEN
              LEAVE getProduct;
         END IF;
        -- build email list
     SET productList =CONCAT(PCViewList,";",productList);   
     END LOOP getProduct;
   CLOSE cursorViewPC;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And after creating the stored procedure, I do,

```
SET @productList = "";

CALL createProductList(@productList);

SELECT @productList;
```

And my output is

`1013;1012;1011;1010;1009;1008;1007;1006;1005;1004;1003;1002;1001;` which are just the model numbers side by side. I am trying to make it look like this -> `"maker '-' type model 'for' price"` and have each listing to be on its own line. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

why not using something like that for each view:

```
select CONCAT(maker,'-',type,' ',model,' for', price) from PCView
union
select CONCAT(maker,'-',type,' ',model,' for', price) from LaptopView
union
select CONCAT(maker,'-',type,' ',model,' for', price) from PrinterView
```

or you can add that column inside each view

also if you want to use cursor , you did the right thing , only missing other columns to fetch each time like below : ( It might have some syntax error but you got the idea)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE createProductList ( INOUT productList varchar(4000) )
BEGIN
     DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE PCViewList varchar(100) DEFAULT "";
     declare maker integer 
            , model integer 
            , type INTEGER
            , model integer 
            , price integer 

     -- declare cursor for PCView
     DEClARE cursorViewPC CURSOR FOR SELECT maker,type,model, price FROM PCView;
     -- declare NOT FOUND handler
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
     OPEN cursorViewPC;
    getProduct: LOOP
          FETCH cursorViewPC INTO maker,type,model, price;
         IF finished = 1 THEN
              LEAVE getProduct;
         END IF;
        -- build email list
     SET productList =CONCAT(productList,';',maker,'-',type,' ',model,' for', price));   
     END LOOP getProduct;
   CLOSE cursorViewPC;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Because I would like to know how to use a cursor to iterate through the views. A stored procedure isn't necessary but I would like to know how we can do it all within a stored procedure. Doing it with just a cursor would be sufficient though. Your commend was helpful anyhow.

Comment: @davenport cursor will be not efficient to solve this problem but if you want use cursor just for the sake of it sure you can do it

Comment: I want to learn how to use cursors and if possible, I'd like to know how to use a cursor within a stored procedure. Efficiency is not a consideration right now.

Comment: @davenport then you are in the right path so far , see the updated reply

Comment: Doesn't feel like I'm on the right path, that is unless you redefined the word 'right'.

Comment: That did not work, gave me syntax errors but I think the logic is wrong on that code you presented as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just figure it out.

If I wanted to insert a newline in here

`SET productList =CONCAT(makerCol," - ",typeCol," ",modelCol," for ",priceCol,"     ", productList);`

for every fetch rather than spaces in between, how could I do so?

Comment: add new line character at the end '\n': SET productList =CONCAT(makerCol," - ",typeCol," ",modelCol," for ",priceCol,"\n", productList);